# Stop visual studio from trying to "Add support for typescript" on each file adding

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have a solution with multiple web projects. And there is common `tsconfig` which is used to build all typescript in solution. Build is called via `webpack`, so I don't want any typescript support from visual studio. More precisely, I want some support — in navigating and refactoring, but I don't want VS to build this code.

So I removed all references to typescript targets from `csproj` and everything works fine. But any time I add a new typescript file, VS gladly says

> Your project has been configured to support TypeScript

and returns all typescript targets back to csproj.

Can I prevent VS from doing it? Of course I can live with it, but removing garbage from csproj after each adding seems uncomfortable.

UPD: found post on uservoice of VS https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13420095-ask-to-configure-projects-for-typescript. But maybe there is solution already available. Or you can like this uservoice if you agree that it is an annoying problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution on uservoice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13420095-ask-to-configure-projects-for-typescript).

Seems a bit ugly but it works.

Steps to fix:

1. Add some ts file to project and let VS add some bullshit to your csproj
2. ctrl-shift-s to make sure csproj is updated
3. Open csproj in any text editor and then:

   1. Find import of `Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props` and replace it's `Condition="..."` to `Condition="false"`
   2. Remove line with `TypeScriptToolsVersion`
   3. Find import of `Microsoft.TypeScript.targets` and replace it's `Condition="..."` to `Condition="false"`

Now after adding file VS will stop trying to do smth with project. And typescript will not be compiled on save and build, so you need to use gulp/webpack/grunt/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2019 (16)

Add to *.csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="**/*.ts" />
    <Content Remove="**/*.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="**/*.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Solution is described here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-modifies-csproj-file-with-typescriptcompile-ite/288648